# Downloaded a branch of Github code as zip, unzipping it and Git Init considers it as Master branch. How to track the remote branch in the local code

Tags: git, github, version-control

Our client VPN connection is extremely slow and Git clone fails continuously. The master branch is only 300mb, but the other project branches are around 1.5Gb. I have created a branch in GitHub from one of the project branches and downloaded this code as a zip. After initializing the local unzipped folder as a git repository using "git init", it considers my code as a master branch.
How do I make git link to my own remote branch instead of master. Below are the steps I did.

git init
git remote add origin https://github.abc.com/ABCProject/ABC.git
git pull origin mybranchname (instead of showing nothing to commit, working tree clean, it starts downloading the whole project again)

Kindly advise and provide some pointers please.

Thanks

Comment: Getting a zip file from GitHub is fine, but be aware that this *does not download a branch*. It downloads a zip archive of *one commit*.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer to your question but rather an alternate method, but have you tried a shallow clone of just the branch ?

`git clone --branch <branch> <url> --depth 1`

Comment: Yes, this was the first thing I tried. It still was a huge project to clone. Thanks for your response. Appreciate it.

Comment: Just tried the following with a very big repo and it works. Can you try this?

1. create a new branch by specifying `--orphan`: `git checkout --orphan foo`

2. commit whatever you want to put on that branch

3. use `git clone --branch foo <url>`

Answer (score 1):

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add -t XYZ origin https://github.abc.com/ABCProject/ABC.git
```

will only track the remote branch `XYZ` and **not** automatically fetch other branches when `git fetch` or `git pull` is executed.

Answer (score 0):

A zip file made on GitHub does not contain anything like a branch.  It contains the *files* from one specific commit, as an archive, and that's all.  (The files may or may not actually match those in the commit, depending on details.  Most importantly, though, it omits the metadata.)  So you cannot use this as a method of obtaining a branch.  Should you need only the *files from one commit*, though, this is a perfectly fine way to get those.

---

Git and GitHub do not currently have a good solution to your issue.  The best you can do here is the single-branch clone as described in [jacky la mouette's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73391207/1256452).

What would help, but is not available directly, is the ability to create a "bundle" (`git bundle`) containing one or more commits, up to the entire repository, and then being able to *restartably* download the bundle file.  If you have access to the Git repository from a faster / more-reliable system, you can clone it there and use `git bundle` to create such a file.  Then you can copy that file over the slow-and-flaky VPN using whatever methods are available, and set up a new repository and `git fetch` from the bundle:

```
$ mkdir new
$ cd new
$ git init
...
$ git add remote origin ../bundle-file
$ git fetch origin
```

for instance.  It's up to you to choose how many commits and branch names to put into the bundle; see [the `git bundle` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle) for more information.